# Is there a way to wake the ios app periodically?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I need my app to wake up every x hours, fetch the data from device and send it to the server.

Is it something doable? If I can implement voip pushkit or fcm?

Thanks.

Comment: What data you need to fetch from device?

Comment: check this - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated

Answer (score 1):

#### Use background task

> Request the system to launch your app in the background to run tasks.

---

#### Thiese articeles might help you.

[Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks)

[BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler)

#### A sample app from Apple.

[Refreshing and Maintaining Your App Using Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks)

#### A WWWDC toturial

[Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/)

Comment: But background task doesn't work if the app is swiped away by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This can somewhat be achieved by VoIP push notifications using PushKit, VoIP push notifications don't appear on a device with no sounds and badges, so one can produce this after every interval and do respective actions on it.
Refer to this link:

https://medium.com/mindful-engineering/voice-over-internet-protocol-voip-801ee15c3722

**OR**

What you can do is before your application goes in the background or terminated you can collect the data and send it to the server. This can be done with this(refer to the code) :

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated

Remember you get only 180sec to do this background task (as per my research).

You can initialize this as

*application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(1800)*.

Every time your application is brought in the background or terminated this function will get a call.

Comment: Voip doesn't fit my case, and found out my app will be rejected if I use it. Other than that I think background tasks don't run if the app is swiped away aka terminated. My function takes 4-6 seconds to complete, so I don't need to do couple minutes long task, but what I need is at least running the function once a day without user intervention.

Comment: background task does work in the terminated mode also, and a 4-6 second can be easily achieved through it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it periodically, but you can do it using VOIP Pushkit, through help of server. But I am not sure if apple allows VOIP without calling feature.

Comment: I read about voip, and no, my app will be rejected if I use it.