# iOS: How do these two apps run in background?

Tags: ios, background-process

The following two apps perform tasks while put in background mode:

1. [System Status Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/system-status-pro-hw-monitor/id401457165)
2. [Mobile Security Protection App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mobile-security-protection-app/id1225777046)

**System Status Pro**

The app monitors cpu usage while in background mode.
The app does **not** use CoreLocation or Notifications.

[image]

**Mobile Security Protection App**

The app send notifications when detects gyro changes i.e. you move the iPhone, also when USB cable is disconnected from the iPhone.
All of this when the app is in background.

[image]

To my knowledge, whether you have to use **CoreLocation** or send **Push Notifications** all the time in order to performs tasks from your app while in background mode.
However, these 2 options, if used out of scope, will lead to AppStore rejection.

How do they do that?

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you ask the developer? ... there may be multiple ways to achieve what you are asking about ... or change your post so that it does not ask about a specific app, but asks something like `what are some of the ways to keep background tasks alive in iOS?`

Comment: There are already such questions asked. All answers state that there is no way to run app in background.

Comment: There is a graph in the app which is populated with data gathered while the app has been put in background mode.

Comment: `no way to run app in background` ... if that is true, then the app probably spends some of its time in foreground

Comment: No such option in the app settings (in iOS Settings of the app). Seems the app does not use push notifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916629/is-there-a-way-to-wake-the-ios-app-periodically

Comment: VoIP push notifications just to run in background will lead to app rejection while in AppleStore review.

Answer (score 1):

[BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) is one way to perform periodic work in the background. There are definitely others; for example, audio apps can play music etc. in the background, apps can download data in the background, and so on. Read up on the [BackgroundTasks framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks).

Comment: Please, read the topic. The apps I talk about they don't play music or download data.

Comment: @Martin I read (and answered) the question before you edited it and substantially changed the content. You had previously claimed that *there are two ways to keep an app alive in the background*, and so I pointed out that there are several other ways for apps to get background time. Furthermore, the answer I gave provides a way that the two apps you point to, and any other app, can get processing time in the background.